# Gradle - auto update dependency version

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have Jenkins CI pipeline which releases applications. This process works in a way that person triggers release job for application. This job checks all project dependencies via gradle dependencies command. For all dependencies that are snapshot release jobs are triggered automatically.
Release job simply upgrade lib/application version and deploys it in artifactory.

How can I automaticaly upgrade SNAPSHOT dependency version to release version in gradle?

My build.gradle file looks like this:

```
Properties versions = new Properties()
versions.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.projectDir.path + "/version.properties"))

dependencies {
    compile("projectA:${versions.projectAVersion}")
    compile("projectB:${versions.projectBVersion}")
}
```

and version.properties file

```
projectAVersion=1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
projectBVersion=1.1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

In fact I am looking something similar to maven versions plugin.

- Is it possible to automatically upgrade version numer inside build.gradle? How?
- And harder version - is it to possible to upgrade version number when version is in external version.properties file?

**EDIT**

In fact I just need Maven versions-plugin (versions:use-releases and versions:use-next-releases) functionality in Gradle.

Comment: What does "automatically upgrade version number" mean? Just strip the `-SNAPSHOT`, or look up the most recently released version and use that, or... ?

Comment: You want to trigger somehow a build when `version.properties` is changed ?

Comment: @lbednaszynski, you mean something like this maven plugin(https://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/usage.html), right?. I have the same requirement in Gradle, but I couldn't find any plugin to update versions automatically like you mentioned. The only plugin I found provides just a report of the latest plugins (https://github.com/ben-manes/gradle-versions-plugin).

Answer (score 0):

I am not that clear with your question. What I understood is that, you need to dynamically update the version value after each build.

What you can do is, get the properties value. Remove -SNAPSHOT. Update 1.1.0 with increment after each build. Like 1.1.1, 1.1.2 etc.

This can be done by

```
      task testing { 
        Properties props = new Properties()
      //getting and loading the property file
      //Give proper path to file
        File propsFile = new File('version.properties')
        props.load(propsFile.newDataInputStream())
       //Now strip of -SNAPSHOT and get the last digit and increment it by 1
            Integer rand = props.getProperty('lastDigit').toInteger()+1
            String variable=rand.toString()
        //Append -SNAPSHOT with 'variable and set the property  
            props.setProperty('version',variable)
            props.store(propsFile.newWriter(), null)
      }
```

This will work, if my understading of your problem is correct.